# Telegram for Android does not seem to support `launchMode=singleTask` for file handling apps

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, telegram

I have an Android react-native app, which should be able to open Json files from messaging apps, but always in the same task. There should never be two instances of the application running. So I have set `launchMode="singleTask"`. Here is a snippet of the manifest:

```
 <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    ...
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    <intent-filter>
      ...
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      <data
         android:scheme="content"
         android:host="*"
         android:pathPattern=".*\\.json"
         android:mimeType="*/*"
       />
    </intent-filter>
  />
```

This works in all applications I tested, except Telegram. Telegram opens a new activity inside its own task. This is shown in the output of `adb shell dumpsys activity activities`, there are two separate activities for `com.myApp` and one is in the Telegram Task:

```
ACTIVITY MANAGER ACTIVITIES (dumpsys activity activities)
Display #0 (activities from top to bottom):
  Stack #1:
  mFullscreen=true
  mBounds=null
    Task id #10571
    mFullscreen=true
    mBounds=null
    mMinWidth=-1
    mMinHeight=-1
    mLastNonFullscreenBounds=null
    * TaskRecord{3bd908f #10571 A=org.telegram.messenger U=0 StackId=1 sz=2}
      userId=0 multiLaunchId=0 effectiveUid=u0a118 mCallingUid=u0a67 mUserSetupComplete=true mCallingPackage=com.huawei.android.launcher
      affinity=org.telegram.messenger
      intent={act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=org.telegram.messenger/org.telegram.ui.LaunchActivity}
      realActivity=org.telegram.messenger/org.telegram.ui.LaunchActivity
      autoRemoveRecents=false isPersistable=true numFullscreen=2 taskType=0 mTaskToReturnTo=1
      rootWasReset=true mNeverRelinquishIdentity=true mReuseTask=false mLockTaskAuth=LOCK_TASK_AUTH_PINNABLE
      Activities=[ActivityRecord{75c4f1c u0 org.telegram.messenger/org.telegram.ui.LaunchActivity t10571}, ActivityRecord{b96c564 u0 com.myApp.debug/com.myApp.MainActivity t10571}]
      askedCompatMode=false inRecents=true isAvailable=true
      lastThumbnail=null lastThumbnailFile=/data/system_ce/0/recent_images/10571_task_thumbnail.png
      stackId=1
      hasBeenVisible=true mResizeMode=RESIZE_MODE_RESIZEABLE isResizeable=true firstActiveTime=1556706462633 lastActiveTime=1556706462633 (inactive for 250s)
      * Hist #1: ActivityRecord{b96c564 u0 com.myApp.debug/com.myApp.MainActivity t10571}
          packageName=com.myApp.debug processName=com.myApp.debug
          launchedFromUid=10118 launchedFromPackage=org.telegram.messenger userId=0 multiLaunchId=0
          app=ProcessRecord{d758be5 11733:com.myApp.debug/u0a187}
          Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://org.telegram.messenger.provider/media/Telegram/Telegram Documents/4_5904235303509427798.json typ=application/octet-stream flg=0x13000001 hwFlg=0x400 cmp=com.myApp.debug/com.myApp.MainActivity }
          frontOfTask=false task=TaskRecord{3bd908f #10571 A=org.telegram.messenger U=0 StackId=1 sz=2}
          taskAffinity=com.myApp.debug
          realActivity=com.myApp.debug/com.myApp.MainActivity
          baseDir=/data/app/com.myApp.debug-2/base.apk
          dataDir=/data/user/0/com.myApp.debug
          stateNotNeeded=false componentSpecified=true mActivityType=0
          compat={480dpi} labelRes=0x7f0b002d icon=0x7f0a0000 theme=0x7f0c0006
          config={1.0 222mcc50mnc [it_IT] ldltr sw360dp w360dp h580dp 480dpi nrml port finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h suim:4 s.6}
          taskConfigOverride={1.0 ?mcc?mnc ?localeList ?layoutDir ?swdp ?wdp ?hdp ?density ?lsize ?long ?orien ?uimode ?night ?touch ?keyb/?/? ?nav/?}
          resultTo=ActivityRecord{75c4f1c u0 org.telegram.messenger/org.telegram.ui.LaunchActivity t10571} resultWho=null resultCode=500
          taskDescription: iconFilename=null label="null" color=fff5f5f5
          readUriPermissions={UriPermission{36a52f7 0 @ content://org.telegram.messenger.provider/media/Telegram/Telegram%20Documents/4_5904235303509427798.json}}
          launchFailed=false launchCount=1 lastLaunchTime=-4m10s762ms
          haveState=false icicle=null
          state=RESUMED stopped=false delayedResume=false finishing=false
          keysPaused=false inHistory=true visible=true sleeping=false idle=true mStartingWindowState=STARTING_WINDOW_NOT_SHOWN
          fullscreen=true noDisplay=false immersive=false launchMode=2
          frozenBeforeDestroy=false forceNewConfig=false
          mActivityType=APPLICATION_ACTIVITY_TYPE
          waitingVisible=false nowVisible=true lastVisibleTime=-4m10s504ms
          resizeMode=RESIZE_MODE_RESIZEABLE
      * Hist #0: ActivityRecord{75c4f1c u0 org.telegram.messenger/org.telegram.ui.LaunchActivity t10571}
          packageName=org.telegram.messenger processName=org.telegram.messenger
          launchedFromUid=10067 launchedFromPackage=com.huawei.android.launcher userId=0 multiLaunchId=0
          app=ProcessRecord{8b7f51e 7395:org.telegram.messenger/u0a118}
          Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=org.telegram.messenger/org.telegram.ui.LaunchActivity bnds=[276,370][540,656] (has extras) }
          frontOfTask=true task=TaskRecord{3bd908f #10571 A=org.telegram.messenger U=0 StackId=1 sz=2}
          taskAffinity=org.telegram.messenger
          realActivity=org.telegram.messenger/org.telegram.ui.LaunchActivity
          baseDir=/data/app/org.telegram.messenger-2/base.apk
          dataDir=/data/user/0/org.telegram.messenger
          stateNotNeeded=false componentSpecified=true mActivityType=0
          compat={480dpi} labelRes=0x7f0c00e0 icon=0x7f0700c0 theme=0x7f0d0015
          config={1.0 222mcc50mnc [it_IT] ldltr sw360dp w360dp h580dp 480dpi nrml port finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h suim:4 s.6}
          taskConfigOverride={1.0 ?mcc?mnc ?localeList ?layoutDir ?swdp ?wdp ?hdp ?density ?lsize ?long ?orien ?uimode ?night ?touch ?keyb/?/? ?nav/?}
          taskDescription: iconFilename=null label="null" color=ff527da3
          launchFailed=false launchCount=0 lastLaunchTime=-4m21s505ms
          haveState=true icicle=Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=1212]
          state=STOPPED stopped=true delayedResume=false finishing=false
          keysPaused=false inHistory=true visible=false sleeping=false idle=true mStartingWindowState=STARTING_WINDOW_SHOWN
          fullscreen=true noDisplay=false immersive=false launchMode=2
          frozenBeforeDestroy=false forceNewConfig=false
          mActivityType=APPLICATION_ACTIVITY_TYPE
          waitingVisible=false nowVisible=false lastVisibleTime=-4m20s756ms
          connections=[]
          resizeMode=RESIZE_MODE_RESIZEABLE
    Task id #10570
    mFullscreen=true
    mBounds=null
    mMinWidth=-1
    mMinHeight=-1
    mLastNonFullscreenBounds=null
    * TaskRecord{575db75 #10570 A=com.myApp.debug U=0 StackId=1 sz=1}
      userId=0 multiLaunchId=0 effectiveUid=u0a187 mCallingUid=2000 mUserSetupComplete=true mCallingPackage=null
      affinity=com.myApp.debug
      intent={flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.myApp.debug/com.myApp.MainActivity}
      realActivity=com.myApp.debug/com.myApp.MainActivity
      autoRemoveRecents=false isPersistable=true numFullscreen=1 taskType=0 mTaskToReturnTo=0
      rootWasReset=false mNeverRelinquishIdentity=true mReuseTask=false mLockTaskAuth=LOCK_TASK_AUTH_PINNABLE
      Activities=[ActivityRecord{d8a470a u0 com.myApp.debug/com.myApp.MainActivity t10570}]
      askedCompatMode=false inRecents=true isAvailable=true
      lastThumbnail=android.graphics.Bitmap@28bc018 lastThumbnailFile=/data/system_ce/0/recent_images/10570_task_thumbnail.png
      stackId=1
      hasBeenVisible=true mResizeMode=RESIZE_MODE_RESIZEABLE isResizeable=true firstActiveTime=1556706445344 lastActiveTime=1556706445344 (inactive for 268s)
      * Hist #0: ActivityRecord{d8a470a u0 com.myApp.debug/com.myApp.MainActivity t10570}
          packageName=com.myApp.debug processName=com.myApp.debug
          launchedFromUid=2000 launchedFromPackage=null userId=0 multiLaunchId=0
          app=ProcessRecord{d758be5 11733:com.myApp.debug/u0a187}
          Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.myApp.debug/com.myApp.MainActivity }
          frontOfTask=true task=TaskRecord{575db75 #10570 A=com.myApp.debug U=0 StackId=1 sz=1}
          taskAffinity=com.myApp.debug
          realActivity=com.myApp.debug/com.myApp.MainActivity
          baseDir=/data/app/com.myApp.debug-2/base.apk
          dataDir=/data/user/0/com.myApp.debug
          stateNotNeeded=false componentSpecified=true mActivityType=0
          compat={480dpi} labelRes=0x7f0b002d icon=0x7f0a0000 theme=0x7f0c0006
          config={1.0 222mcc50mnc [it_IT] ldltr sw360dp w360dp h580dp 480dpi nrml port finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h suim:4 s.6}
          taskConfigOverride={1.0 ?mcc?mnc ?localeList ?layoutDir ?swdp ?wdp ?hdp ?density ?lsize ?long ?orien ?uimode ?night ?touch ?keyb/?/? ?nav/?}
          taskDescription: iconFilename=null label="null" color=fff5f5f5
          launchFailed=false launchCount=0 lastLaunchTime=-17m43s658ms
          haveState=true icicle=Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=2808]
          state=STOPPED stopped=true delayedResume=false finishing=false
          keysPaused=false inHistory=true visible=false sleeping=false idle=true mStartingWindowState=STARTING_WINDOW_SHOWN
          fullscreen=true noDisplay=false immersive=false launchMode=2
          frozenBeforeDestroy=false forceNewConfig=false
          mActivityType=APPLICATION_ACTIVITY_TYPE
          waitingVisible=false nowVisible=false lastVisibleTime=-17m42s676ms
          resizeMode=RESIZE_MODE_RESIZEABLE
    Running activities (most recent first):
      TaskRecord{3bd908f #10571 A=org.telegram.messenger U=0 StackId=1 sz=2}
        Run #6: ActivityRecord{b96c564 u0 com.myApp.debug/com.myApp.MainActivity t10571}
        Run #5: ActivityRecord{75c4f1c u0 org.telegram.messenger/org.telegram.ui.LaunchActivity t10571}
      TaskRecord{575db75 #10570 A=com.myApp.debug U=0 StackId=1 sz=1}
        Run #4: ActivityRecord{d8a470a u0 com.myApp.debug/com.myApp.MainActivity t10570}
```

Again, this does not happen in other messengers (Signal, Whatsapp), consistently with the `singleTask` launch mode. Has anyone experienced a similar problem? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Sounds incredibly hard to believe. How do you know that your `Activity` is launched into an existing Telegram task?

Comment: I know it's a strange behavior. But if I open the recent apps list a new instance of my application is there with the header of Telegram.

Comment: Please use `adb shell dumpsys activity activities`. This will show you all tasks and their activities. Please post this in your question, that will help.

Comment: Added the relevant information. This is puzzling.